# Weird behavior with conditional formatting

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have added the following two equations to conditional formatting:

Green: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"),5, FALSE), "Likes"), R2>=VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"), 4, FALSE), T2>=VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"), 4, FALSE))`

Red: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"),5, FALSE), "Likes"),   NOT(R2>=VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"), 4, FALSE)),   NOT(T2>=VLOOKUP(X2, INDIRECT("DEALS!$A$2:F"), 4, FALSE)))`

The colors should change accordingly depending on whether the target (views in this case) has been met or not.

[image: Target vs. Live Views]

Below I have also added the equation into the cells to check if the logic is correct, which it appears to be (left = green logic, right = red logic).

[image: Logic check in cells]

For whatever reason, the first row, despite the target not being met, has decided to select the green color. The row below that is doing the complete opposite. And to top it all off, the last two rows are not selecting a color at all even though I have applied the conditional formatting to the entire column:

[image: Conditional formatting applied to entire column P]

I am also experiencing weird behavior when dragging equations within this P column, but do not see this same behavior in other columns that also use conditional formatting:

https://i.gyazo.com/5e002e3d08e8337591573b81d9fc92e2.mp4

This has left me completely baffled, and I am not sure what is going on since the equation's logic does not appear to be the issue.

Appreciate any help I can get with this issue!

For reference, here is the other sheet that the VLOOKUP() function is grabbing from:

[image: DEALS Sheet]

Comment: Will you be able to share a sample sheet to be able to [reproduce the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your custom function for conditional formatting?

Comment: Thanks. Upon checking, dragging the cells on column `P` doesn't make any changes that would affect the calculation of your custom formula, which in theory should still meet the conditional format rules. This seems like a possible isolated issue with the core Sheets behavior. To report this type of issue _(unrelated to any Google API issues)_, open your **Sheets file** and at the top, click **Help** > **Help us improve** & include all of the details for the issue. You can also ask for additional help from the [Google Docs community experts](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/new).

Comment: @IrvinJayG. Hi Irvin, thanks for the response. I'm going to add one more screenshot of the table on my other sheet which might help understand better what the formula is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not lock (`$`) references inside `INDIRECT`. if stuff is between double quotes it's a text string, not an active reference, and text strings are not affected by dragging.

for green use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 5, 0), "Likes"), 
 R2>=VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0), 
 T2>=VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0))
```

for red use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 5, 0), "Likes"),   
 NOT(R2>=VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0)),   
 NOT(T2>=VLOOKUP(Z2, INDIRECT("DEALS!A2:F"), 4, 0)))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jD-K4wbJu5Qs-WbxLCm_xB9lxv8HZTkyG-Zss6wvQ2s/edit#gid=0)

---

### update:

don't drag anything. use this in P2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(TEXT(VLOOKUP(Z2:Z,DEALS!A2:F,4,0), 
 "#,###,##0")& " " &VLOOKUP(Z2:Z,DEALS!A2:F,5,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: So I just tried your changes, and although initially after adding the equations it seemed that everything was fixed, once you start changing the targets the colors do not update to match.

The formula dragging issue also remains.

https://gyazo.com/9a337c174c22ac54e58f5bee780de076

Are you seeing this on your end?

Comment: @dan I'm trying to reproduce it but so far no luck. so far everything works on my end

Comment: @dan https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jD-K4wbJu5Qs-WbxLCm_xB9lxv8HZTkyG-Zss6wvQ2s/edit#gid=0